# ¿Cómo mostrar un documento PDF desde un servidor FTP sin descargarlo?

Tags: php, ftp

Como dice el título, lo que quiero realizar es mostrar un documento PDF con PHP sin la necesidad de descargarlo en un servidor local, simplemente me quiero loguear al fpt y mostrar el archivo.

Para darles un panorama de lo que quiero hacer seria algo como lo siguiente:

```
      <?php 
        $ftp_server="xxx"; 
        $ftp_user_name="xxx"; 
        $ftp_user_pass="xxx"; 

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

        /* Ejecutar algo para mostrar archivo sin descargarlo */

        ftp_close($conn_id); 
        ?>
```

Se que quizás falten algunos headers para espero se entienda la idea.

Saludos

Comment: gracias funciona perfecto pero para hacer lo mismo para imágenes, jpg, png, o archivos de offices???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto me funcionó perfecto:

```
        <?php 

        $mi_pdf = fopen ("ftp://usuarioftp:contraseñaftp@servidor/public_html/proyecto.pdf", "r");
        if (!$mi_pdf) {
            echo "<p>No puedo abrir el archivo para lectura</p>";
            exit;
        }
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        fpassthru($mi_pdf); // Esto hace la magia
        fclose ($archivo);

        ?>
```

Obviamente debes cambiar los parámetros usuario, contraseña, y servidor

[Referencia fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fpassthru.php)

Así queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciono perfectamente,